# bash function parameters by index - difference between head and echo

Tags: bash

I'm confused as to the odd behaviour in the "head" command when accessing function parameters.
Here's the code:

```
function fun1 { echo $1; head $1; }
```

And here are the outputs of 2 different function calls

```
echo "asasa" | fun1
--- output start ---

asasa
--- end ---
```

and when passing a parameter:

```
echo "asasa" | fun1 "var1"
--- output start ---
var1
head: cannot open `var1' for reading: No such file or directory
--- end ---
```

What exactly is happening in the accessing parameter 1 ($1) and why are head and echo interpreting it very differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$1` always refers to the first *argument* passed on the command line, which is separate from any input via *stdin*.

`head` expects as its (non-option) arguments one or more *filenames* - in the absence of one, input is read from *stdin*. (Many utilities that process *file content* behave this way).

`echo "asasa" | fun1` ... stdin input only, no arguments (`$1` not set):

- `echo $1` echoes an empty line (just `\n`), because `$1` is not set.
- `head $1` echoes (up to 10 lines from) *stdin* (`asasa`): because `$1` is unset, it's as if *no* arguments were passed to `head`, so it reads from *stdin*.

`echo "asasa" | fun1 "var1"` ... both stdin input and 1 argument: `$1` set to `var1`.

- `echo $1` echoes `var1`, the value assigned to `$1`.
- `head $1` reports an *error*, because `var1` is interpreted as a *filename*, and no such file exists; *stdin input* is *ignored* in this case.

If you want `echo` to access the *argument* and `head` to access *stdin input*, simply drop the `$1` argument from the `head` command:

```
function fun1 { echo $1; head; }
```

Conversely, if you really want to process the string passed via argument `$1` with `head`, you must explicitly provide it via *stdin* *inside* the script (e.g., via `<<<`):

```
function fun1 { echo $1; head <<<"$1"; }
```

Comment: Can you also add this clarification why `echo | fun1` didn't give any error.

Comment: @anubhava: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but hopefully my update addresses your suggestion. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`head` reads input from stdin only if it's arguments are empty. Since you passed an argument to it, it tried to read it instead.

```
Usage: head [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print the first 10 lines of each FILE to standard output.
With more than one FILE, precede each with a header giving the file name.
With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.
```